# Concatenating Multiple columns in an Access table to one specific row

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have been on the web searching for answers and I just can not find one that works (I'm sure it is something I am not doing right)

I have a table in Access called TBL003_Combined Data that has the following columns:
 UPLOADED, REF ID, QTY, PART NUMBER, ITEM DESCRIPTION, SHIP TO
 4/8/2015, 123, 20, 9125xtr, sample item, XYZ Company, 789 Address Lane, Somewhere,US 159632
 4/8/2015, 123, 16, 22578xtz, sample item2, XYZ Company, 789 Address Lane, Somewhere,US 159632
 4/8/2015, 123, 8, 7758rty, sample item3, XYZ Company, 789 Address Lane, Somewhere,US 159632

What I am trying to do is for each unique [REF ID], I want to concatenate the QTY, [PART NUMBER], [ITEM DESCRIPTION] & [SHIP TO] to a new column called [CS_ITEM DESCRIPTION].

I have tried the following in Allen Brown's site:

```
Public Function ConcatRelated(strField As String, _
    strTable As String, _
    Optional strWhere As String, _
    Optional strOrderBy As String, _
    Optional strSeparator = ", ") As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   Generate a concatenated string of related records.
    'Return:    String variant, or Null if no matches.
    'Arguments: strField = name of field to get results from and concatenate.
    '           strTable = name of a table or query.
    '           strWhere = WHERE clause to choose the right values.
    '           strOrderBy = ORDER BY clause, for sorting the values.
    '           strSeparator = characters to use between the concatenated values.
    'Notes:     1. Use square brackets around field/table names with spaces or odd characters.
    '           2. strField can be a Multi-valued field (A2007 and later), but strOrderBy cannot.
    '           3. Nulls are omitted, zero-length strings (ZLSs) are returned as ZLSs.
    '           4. Returning more than 255 characters to a recordset triggers this Access bug:
    '               http://allenbrowne.com/bug-16.html
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset         'Related records
    Dim rsMV As DAO.Recordset       'Multi-valued field recordset
    Dim strSQL As String            'SQL statement
    Dim strOut As String            'Output string to concatenate to.
    Dim lngLen As Long              'Length of string.
    Dim bIsMultiValue As Boolean    'Flag if strField is a multi-valued field.

    'Initialize to Null
    ConcatRelated = Null

    'Build SQL string, and get the records.
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT " & strField & " FROM " & strTable
    If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If
    If strOrderBy <> vbNullString Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY " & strOrderBy
    End If
    Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    'Determine if the requested field is multi-valued (Type is above 100.)
    bIsMultiValue = (rs(0).Type > 100)

    'Loop through the matching records
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If bIsMultiValue Then
            'For multi-valued field, loop through the values
            Set rsMV = rs(0).Value
            Do While Not rsMV.EOF
                If Not IsNull(rsMV(0)) Then
                    strOut = strOut & rsMV(0) & strSeparator
                End If
                rsMV.MoveNext
            Loop
            Set rsMV = Nothing
        ElseIf Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
            strOut = strOut & rs(0) & strSeparator
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

    'Return the string without the trailing separator.
    lngLen = Len(strOut) - Len(strSeparator)
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ConcatRelated = Left(strOut, lngLen)
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    'Clean up
    Set rsMV = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ConcatRelated()"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

and my query I've used the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [REF ID],
    ConcatRelated("[QTY],[PART NUMBER], [ITEM DESCRIPTION], [SHIP TO]",
        "[TBL003_Combined Data]",
        "[REF ID] = " & [REF ID],
        "("[QTY],[PART NUMBER], [ITEM DESCRIPTION], [SHIP TO]",
        "/"
        ) AS CS_ITEM DESCRIPTIONS
FROM [TBL003_Combined Data];
```

and I keep getting the following error:

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression...."

then it list the entire SQL I'm referencing above (Select Distinct). Any help in pointing me in the right direction or advising why I am doing wrong (as I'm certain it's me) will be greatly appreciated.

added: The result I'm trying to reach is for the data to come out as follows:

UPLOADED, REF ID, CS_ITEM DESCRIPTION
 4/8/2015, 123, 20 / 9125xtr / sample item / 16 / 22578xtz /sample item2 / 8 / 7758rty / sample item3 / XYZ Company, 789 Address Lane, Somewhere,US 159632

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct [REF ID],
[QTY] + ' ' + [PART NUMBER] + ' ' + [ITEM DESCRIPTION] + ' ' + [SHIP TO] 
AS 'CS_ITEM DESCRIPTIONS' 
FROM [TBL003_Combined Data];
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy W but it is still giving me a syntax error. Also, I think the (+) acts like the (& "  ",) string as it will join each line but I need the entire columns combined into one row.  I've been racking out my brains so any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean, 'columns combined into one row' if you don't mean concatenated?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  I do want  to concatenate items in 4 different columns into one field (row) (like sample data above).  the "+" did not work, still came up as a syntax error and I thought the "+" was like the "&", I've tried that but it only concatenates per row and I need the entire columns concatenated in one cell (row).  Is this even possible?  Currently, I'm performing this in Excel then importing data into the database with the results I have, maybe this is the only way I can achieve my goal.  Any advice to help me do this in Access would be greatly appreciated.